# Converting call to a stored procedure from C# to VB.net

Tags: stored-procedures, c#-to-vb.net

```
Dim sql1 As String = ("EXEC [dbo].[usp_GetReportData_All] @ReportID=N'{0}', @StartDate=N'{1}' @EndDate=N'{2}', @StartDate2=N'{3}' @EndDate2=N'{4}'", repotid1, startdata1, EndDate1, StartDate3,Enddate3 ) (this is what I tried to do in VB.net)
```

Ok normally I have this line of code in C# saved into a string then from there I use that string to run the stored procedure into a datatable. Apparently vb.net doesn't seem to like that format so I'm just wondering if it is possible to save this line into a string or not in vb.net

Oops mistake, this is what I do in C#:

```
string srcSQL = string.Format(then the line in parans up there)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this examples of Console.Writeline(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa324760(v=vs.71).aspx), you can use it for example:

`Console.WriteLine("Grand total:\t{0,8:c}", Total);`

For Example

```
    Dim total As String
    Dim result As String
    total = "1000"
    result = String.Format("restulado {0}", total)
    MsgBox(result)
```

The var Total is formatted as currency

Answer (score 0):

use String.Format("YourSQLText", parameter0, parameter1)

Comment: This is actually a prime example of what not to do.  Never use string.format to construct SQL queries, use [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521.aspx).

Comment: Is there any particular reason why not to format SQL queries in string?

Comment: You can be victim of SQL Injection, but I really don't know why the negative point hahaha, the question was about the format, nor the best way

Comment: Thanks crassr3cords for your answer and w.brian for your reponse.